# Disable onBackPressed only in ONE fragment - Android

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

Im trying with no success to disable the back key only in one fragment, in the first one.
I did the override of the `onBackPressed` method on the Activity that contains the fragment with this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        //getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

So, it works perfectly. **BUT** when i finish all the path of fragments, at the final fragment i have a button that take me back to the first fragment. I will paste the code where i load this fragment again.

```
for (Fragment fragment1:getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment1).commit();
    }

    MontoFragment montoFragment = new MontoFragment();
    cargarFragment(montoFragment);
```

And here the "cargarFragment()" method

```
public void cargarFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.animation_slide_in,R.anim.animation_slide_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layoutContenedorFragments,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

After i complete all the fragments and i go back to the first one with that, my `onBackPressed` method doesnt work anymore, because `this.fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()` > 1 now is 5 or 6 i dont remember now. And this make the back key enable.

So i dont know what to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `popBackStack`, replace code block:

```
for (Fragment fragment1:getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment1).commit();
    }

    MontoFragment montoFragment = new MontoFragment();
    cargarFragment(montoFragment);
```

by

```
 void popFragments(int number) {
        for (int i = 0, i < number, i++) {
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
        }
    }
```

`number` here is the number of fragments you want to remove, ex: we have fragment 1,2,3,4, so when we are in fragment 4 and want to back to fragment 1, so the number will be `3`.

Comment: i posted an answer that it seems to work. CHek it! The problem of this solutions could be that when i remove the 3 fragments i got the fragment 1 but with the data setted that i setted before?

Answer (score 0):

I just achieve it with this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.layoutContenedorFragments);
    if (currentFragment instanceof MontoFragment){

    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

i got the current fragment and if this one is an instanceOf That Fragment just do nothing but if not just do the normal onBackPressed.

I look that it works great